# Order By checking several nulls

Tags: java, sql, hql

I have a table with the following timestamp columns:

**Table: Alerts**

**Created**, **Acknowledged**, **Ignored**

An alert is considered active if both AcknowledgedDate and IgnoredDate are null. It is considered acknowledged if AcknowledgedDate is not null but IgnoredDate is null. It is considered ignored if IgnoredDate is not null.

For my query, I need to order alerts in the order Active -> Acknowledged -> Ignored -> Created. So, I don't care about any of the actual dates except for CreatedOn, which is used when comparing two alerts that are both active or acknowledged or ignored.

```
SELECT alrt FROM ALERT alrt ORDER BY ???
```

Comment: Sample data and desire results would clarify your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `case` logic:

```
order by (case when AcknowledgedDate is null and IgnoredDate then 1
               when IgnoredDate is null then 2
               else 3
          end)
```

Comment: What about created?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi . . . It would seem to fall in the third group.  It is not explicitly mentioned in the conditions for the other two.  However, I would expect it to never be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your conditions this will do:

```
SELECT * FROM ALERT 
ORDER BY 
  AcknowledgedDate IS NULL AND IgnoredDate IS NULL DESC,
  AcknowledgedDate IS NOT NULL AND IgnoredDate IS NULL DESC,
  IgnoredDate IS NOT NULL DESC
```